# custom class property in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, naming-conventions

What is best practice for naming custom property in ExtJS?
Is it a good idea to precede name with an underline?

```
Ext.create("Ext.Window,{
   height:50,
   _custom:"xxx",
   _action:"yyyy"
});
```

another idea is using **data_** prefix to mimic html5 custom attribute convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to to use `_` as a prefix for custom variables. because:

- It prevent any collision
- Self-documenting
- It's users friendly

It would be better if Sencha used a mechanism to prevent the mixing up.

Answer (score 4):

I personally don't like anything in a variable name that carries additional syntactic information (Uncle Bob dedicates a whole section to this principle in [http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)), not to mention the ugly code it produces (e.g. `mywindow._custom`).

I would just give your variables descriptive names, and then your code will read better and you shouldn't have to worry about collision with Ext properties (if you were worried about).

I like this much better:

```
Ext.create("Ext.Window,{
   height:50,
   customNameOfSomething:"xxx",
   actionToPerform:"yyyy"
});
```

Comment: Do you mean that W3C make mistake in introducing data- prifix and namespacings technique in other programming languages is useless?

Comment: I would say their mistake was not supporting custom attributes to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with others, and will add that the underscore in particular is more or less an accepted standard for private variables in most syntaxes (though Ext JS itself does not use it, and keeps private variables marked as private via comments or undocumented by convention). I definitely would choose some other way to name public configs if you insist on choosing some convention, though I agree with others that it's probably not necessary. I would guess that in most real cases, your custom properties are not going to be so generic as to clash (and if they are, you probably chose poor names for whatever you're adding).

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that you're designing a custom property that might be used by others. This means that it has to be descriptive of its behavior. That's what is most important. Using an _ is very rare and isn't really natural to developers using the code, so it's gotta be user friendly.

Comment: So how we can prevent collisions?

Comment: I guess brian answered your question. :)